# How can I use cordova plugin functions in my angular 7 component.ts files?

Tags: angular, cordova, angular7, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a cordova application where I have installed some plugin like device, appversion.
On device ready these plugins return some global `variables` like `device`.
For UI code I am using angular 7.

How can i use cordova variable inside angular component?

If there is any variable declaration at angular side then I want to do that in only one file and want to use that  file in whole angular application.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this using by storing all your global variables from cordova into a service that is shared in root.

In your `app.component` or your root component, declare these variables:

```
//Use "declare" to have variables that store cordova and pluggins before Component declaration
declare var StatusBar: any;
declare var cordova: any;
declare var window:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

In the component constructor inject a service that would store the details:

```
//In constructor you inject a service (you can call it cordovaService)
constructor(private cordovaService:CordovaService){}
```

You must add in `ngAfterViewInit`  and add `document.addEventListener('device ready')`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
  }
```

In `onDeviceReady`, you can process and store cordova related stuff:

```
onDeviceReady() {
this.cordovaService.cordova=cordova;

 cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(appVersion => {
      console.log(appVersion);
    });

 }
```

Now any component that inject `CordovaService` would be able to access and use this data/variable.

Comment: hi @nircraft thank you for the answer.I did it other way by using window object directly into my component.      declare var window:any;  and assigning this variable in class like     window:any=window;

Comment: @UmeshSinghal, that works too. I just tried to give a cleaner approach by using services. glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @nircraft where is CordovaService defined?

Comment: @SarahJames, We are injecting this service in Constructor of component. You can create a service with whatever name and inject in the component where you need it